# How to process same files multiple times in spring integration file polling, which means I want to process the file even it's processed already

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-file

I have a spring integration file polling implementation which is polling a specific directory, during the process file will be picked and file related metadata being passed to downstream systems. Some scenarios same file I wanted to process again from file polling directory, currently which is not accepting. I belive some state will be maintained while processing that file first time, but I wanted to process that, is there anyway to allow duplicate file processing even if it's processed already. Which filter needs to overrided? Also tried preventDuplicates is false , no luck. Tried with some custom filter which implements FileListFilter, but it's not being invoked from my DSL filter. Any suggestions or cleaner way?

Tried custom implementation not worked out`

```
your text
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By default files are not processed again and again. The `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` is used by default.

You need to look into `AcceptAllFileListFilter`:

```
Files.inboundAdapter(directory)
    .filter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>())
```

Comment: Even if am adding that filter AcceptAllFileListFilter in my DSL with preventDuplicate is false, still it's invoking AcceptonceFileListFilter. How to override this default behaviour, after debugging I can see seenSet maintaining already processed file names due to this am not able to process same file again. Any suggestions?

Comment: After adding AcceptAllFileListFilter my expectation should get invoked this filter instead of default one and return true from the accept method, which is not happening at the moment.

Comment: You must just do only `.filter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>())` - nothing more. You might have some other `Files.inboundAdapter` instances which you can see in your debug session.